# I am new to JS and jinja2. I am wondering why I am getting this syntax error? The error is occurring in the for loop

Tags: python, flask, chart.js, jinja2

```
    var lineData = {
         labels : [
             {% for item in labels %}
                "{{ item }}",
             {% endfor %}
         ],
```

I am getting an error in the for loop. I am not sure where I am going wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Never mind to anyone that answers. I think I must convert my labels list in my views function to json data.

Comment: never mind that did not work. It seems I cannot use {{ object }} when using javascript. I am not sure how to get around this. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data to JavaScript within a template using the jinja filter [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson).

```
var lineData = {
   labels : {{ labels | tojson }},
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I finally realized that VS code just detects as not valid JS

Comment: It is only partially JavaScript, which VSCode does not recognize. However, the code is correct and works.